# Sql Server CLR SqlFunction FillRowMethod throwing error on "void" in declaration

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, clr, sql-function

I am writing my first CLR SQLFunction but I am getting a build error on 'void' in the declaration of the FillRowMethod . Here is the full code listing for the SQLFunction:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;
using System;
using System.Data;

namespace AFLFootballCLR
{
public partial class LadderUserDefinedFunctions
{
    private class Ladder
    {
        public SqlInt32 Id;
        public SqlInt32 TeamId;
        public SqlInt32 Played;
        public SqlInt32 Won;
        public SqlInt32 Draw;
        public SqlInt32 Lost;
        public SqlInt32 PtsFor;
        public SqlInt32 PtsAgainst;
        public SqlInt32 Pts;

        public Ladder(SqlInt32 id, SqlInt32 teamId, SqlInt32 played, SqlInt32 won, SqlInt32 draw, SqlInt32 lost, SqlInt32 ptsFor, SqlInt32 ptsAgainst, SqlInt32 pts)
        {
            this.Id = id;
            this.TeamId = teamId;
            this.Played = played;
            this.Won = won;
            this.Draw = draw;
            this.Lost = lost;
            this.PtsFor = ptsFor;
            this.PtsAgainst = ptsAgainst;
            this.Pts = pts;
        }

    }


    [SqlFunction(DataAccess = DataAccessKind.Read, FillRowMethodName = "Ladder_FillRow", TableDefinition = "Id int, TeamId int, Played int, Won int, Draw int, Lost int, PtsFor int, PtsAgainst int, Pts int")]
    public static IEnumerable GetLadder(SqlInt32 s)
    {

        //int season = s;
        int iplayed = 0;
        int iwon = 0;
        int idraw = 0;
        int ilost = 0;
        int iforPts = 0;
        int iagainstPts = 0;
        int ipts = 0;
        int tempId = 0;
        Dictionary<int, string> withTeam = new Dictionary<int, string>();
        string connectionString = "Data Source=EAGLE;Initial Catalog=AFLFooty;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=Colinmck0708";
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (var teamsFromDb = new SqlCommand("Select Id, TeamName From Teams", connection))
            {
            using (var teamReader = teamsFromDb.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (teamReader.Read())
                {
                    int teamId = teamReader.GetInt32(0);
                    string teamName = teamReader.GetString(1);
                    withTeam.Add(teamId, teamName);
                }
                teamReader.Close();
                foreach (KeyValuePair<int, string> kvp in withTeam)
                {
                    int TeamId = kvp.Key;
                    string teamName = kvp.Value;
                    if (teamName != "Bye")
                    {
                        using (var resultsFromDb = new SqlCommand("SELECT QtrByQtrs.Fixture_ID, QtrByQtrs.HPoints, QtrByQtrs.APoints, Fixtures.HomeID, Fixtures.AwayID FROM QtrByQtrs INNER JOIN Fixtures ON QtrByQtrs.Fixture_ID = Fixtures.ID WHERE ((Fixtures.HomeID = " + TeamId + ") AND (QtrByQtrs.Qtr = 4) AND (Fixtures.SeasonID = @s)) OR ((Fixtures.AwayID = " + TeamId + ") AND (QtrByQtrs.Qtr = 4) AND (Fixtures.SeasonID = @s))", connection))
                        {
                        using (var resultsReader = resultsFromDb.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            while (resultsReader.Read())
                            {
                                if (resultsReader.GetInt32(3) == TeamId)
                                {
                                    if (!(Convert.IsDBNull(resultsReader.GetInt32(1))) & !(Convert.IsDBNull(resultsReader.GetInt32(2))))
                                    {
                                        iplayed += 1;
                                        if (resultsReader.GetInt32(1) > resultsReader.GetInt32(2))
                                        {
                                            iwon += 1;
                                            ipts += 4;
                                        }
                                        else if (resultsReader.GetInt32(1) < resultsReader.GetInt32(2))
                                        {
                                            ilost += 1;
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            idraw += 1;
                                            ipts += 2;
                                        }
                                        iforPts += resultsReader.GetInt32(1);
                                        iagainstPts += resultsReader.GetInt32(2);
                                    }
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    if (!(Convert.IsDBNull(resultsReader.GetInt32(1))) & !(Convert.IsDBNull(resultsReader.GetInt32(2))))
                                    {
                                        iplayed += 1;
                                        if (resultsReader.GetInt32(1) < resultsReader.GetInt32(2))
                                        {
                                            iwon += 1;
                                            ipts += 4;
                                        }
                                        else if (resultsReader.GetInt32(1) > resultsReader.GetInt32(2))
                                        {
                                            ilost += 1;
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            idraw += 1;
                                            ipts += 2;
                                        }
                                        iforPts += resultsReader.GetInt32(2);
                                        iagainstPts += resultsReader.GetInt32(1);
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                            resultsReader.Close();
                        }
                        }
                    }
                    if (teamName != "Bye")
                    {
                        yield return new Ladder(id: tempId, teamId: TeamId, played: iplayed, won: iwon, draw: idraw, lost: ilost, ptsFor: iforPts, ptsAgainst: iagainstPts, pts: ipts);
                        tempId += 1;
                    }
                    iplayed = 0;
                    iwon = 0;
                    idraw = 0;
                    ilost = 0;
                    iforPts = 0;
                    iagainstPts = 0;
                    ipts = 0;

                }
            }
            }
        }
    }

}


public static void Ladder_FillRow(object ladderObj, out SqlInt32 id, out SqlInt32 teamId, out SqlInt32 played, out SqlInt32 won, out SqlInt32 draw, out SqlInt32 lost, out SqlInt32 ptsFor, out SqlInt32 ptsAgainst, out SqlInt32 pts)
{
    var l = (Ladder)ladderObj;

    id = l.Id;
    teamId = l.TeamId;
    played = l.Played;
    won = l.Won;
    draw = l.Draw;
    lost = l.Lost;
    ptsFor = l.PtsFor;
    ptsAgainst = l.PtsAgainst;
    pts = l.Pts;

}
```

};

Any help as to the cause of this would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you're seeing is `Expected class, delegate, enum, interface or struct`.

This indicates the function declaration for `ladder_FillRow` is not contained inside a class.  You need to move the function inside the `Ladder` class like:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;
using System;
using System.Data;

namespace AFLFootballCLR
{
    public partial class LadderUserDefinedFunctions
    {
        private class Ladder
        {
            public SqlInt32 Id;
            public SqlInt32 TeamId;
            public SqlInt32 Played;
            public SqlInt32 Won;
            public SqlInt32 Draw;
            public SqlInt32 Lost;
            public SqlInt32 PtsFor;
            public SqlInt32 PtsAgainst;
            public SqlInt32 Pts;

            public Ladder(SqlInt32 id, SqlInt32 teamId, SqlInt32 played, SqlInt32 won, SqlInt32 draw, SqlInt32 lost, SqlInt32 ptsFor, SqlInt32 ptsAgainst, SqlInt32 pts)
            {
                this.Id = id;
                this.TeamId = teamId;
                this.Played = played;
                this.Won = won;
                this.Draw = draw;
                this.Lost = lost;
                this.PtsFor = ptsFor;
                this.PtsAgainst = ptsAgainst;
                this.Pts = pts;
            }

        }


        [SqlFunction(DataAccess = DataAccessKind.Read, FillRowMethodName = "Ladder_FillRow", TableDefinition = "Id int, TeamId int, Played int, Won int, Draw int, Lost int, PtsFor int, PtsAgainst int, Pts int")]
        public static IEnumerable GetLadder(SqlInt32 s)
        {

            //int season = s;
            int iplayed = 0;
            int iwon = 0;
            int idraw = 0;
            int ilost = 0;
            int iforPts = 0;
            int iagainstPts = 0;
            int ipts = 0;
            int tempId = 0;
            Dictionary<int, string> withTeam = new Dictionary<int, string>();
            string connectionString = "Data Source=EAGLE;Initial Catalog=AFLFooty;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=Colinmck0708";
            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                using (var teamsFromDb = new SqlCommand("Select Id, TeamName From Teams", connection))
                {
                    using (var teamReader = teamsFromDb.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (teamReader.Read())
                        {
                            int teamId = teamReader.GetInt32(0);
                            string teamName = teamReader.GetString(1);
                            withTeam.Add(teamId, teamName);
                        }
                        teamReader.Close();
                        foreach (KeyValuePair<int, string> kvp in withTeam)
                        {
                            int TeamId = kvp.Key;
                            string teamName = kvp.Value;
                            if (teamName != "Bye")
                            {
                                using (var resultsFromDb = new SqlCommand("SELECT QtrByQtrs.Fixture_ID, QtrByQtrs.HPoints, QtrByQtrs.APoints, Fixtures.HomeID, Fixtures.AwayID FROM QtrByQtrs INNER JOIN Fixtures ON QtrByQtrs.Fixture_ID = Fixtures.ID WHERE ((Fixtures.HomeID = " + TeamId + ") AND (QtrByQtrs.Qtr = 4) AND (Fixtures.SeasonID = @s)) OR ((Fixtures.AwayID = " + TeamId + ") AND (QtrByQtrs.Qtr = 4) AND (Fixtures.SeasonID = @s))", connection))
                                {
                                    using (var resultsReader = resultsFromDb.ExecuteReader())
                                    {
                                        while (resultsReader.Read())
                                        {
                                            if (resultsReader.GetInt32(3) == TeamId)
                                            {
                                                if (!(Convert.IsDBNull(resultsReader.GetInt32(1))) & !(Convert.IsDBNull(resultsReader.GetInt32(2))))
                                                {
                                                    iplayed += 1;
                                                    if (resultsReader.GetInt32(1) > resultsReader.GetInt32(2))
                                                    {
                                                        iwon += 1;
                                                        ipts += 4;
                                                    }
                                                    else if (resultsReader.GetInt32(1) < resultsReader.GetInt32(2))
                                                    {
                                                        ilost += 1;
                                                    }
                                                    else
                                                    {
                                                        idraw += 1;
                                                        ipts += 2;
                                                    }
                                                    iforPts += resultsReader.GetInt32(1);
                                                    iagainstPts += resultsReader.GetInt32(2);
                                                }
                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                                if (!(Convert.IsDBNull(resultsReader.GetInt32(1))) & !(Convert.IsDBNull(resultsReader.GetInt32(2))))
                                                {
                                                    iplayed += 1;
                                                    if (resultsReader.GetInt32(1) < resultsReader.GetInt32(2))
                                                    {
                                                        iwon += 1;
                                                        ipts += 4;
                                                    }
                                                    else if (resultsReader.GetInt32(1) > resultsReader.GetInt32(2))
                                                    {
                                                        ilost += 1;
                                                    }
                                                    else
                                                    {
                                                        idraw += 1;
                                                        ipts += 2;
                                                    }
                                                    iforPts += resultsReader.GetInt32(2);
                                                    iagainstPts += resultsReader.GetInt32(1);
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }

                                        resultsReader.Close();
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            if (teamName != "Bye")
                            {
                                yield return new Ladder(id: tempId, teamId: TeamId, played: iplayed, won: iwon, draw: idraw, lost: ilost, ptsFor: iforPts, ptsAgainst: iagainstPts, pts: ipts);
                                tempId += 1;
                            }
                            iplayed = 0;
                            iwon = 0;
                            idraw = 0;
                            ilost = 0;
                            iforPts = 0;
                            iagainstPts = 0;
                            ipts = 0;

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }



        public static void Ladder_FillRow(object ladderObj, out SqlInt32 id, out SqlInt32 teamId, out SqlInt32 played, out SqlInt32 won, out SqlInt32 draw, out SqlInt32 lost, out SqlInt32 ptsFor, out SqlInt32 ptsAgainst, out SqlInt32 pts)
        {
            var l = (Ladder)ladderObj;

            id = l.Id;
            teamId = l.TeamId;
            played = l.Played;
            won = l.Won;
            draw = l.Draw;
            lost = l.Lost;
            ptsFor = l.PtsFor;
            ptsAgainst = l.PtsAgainst;
            pts = l.Pts;

        }
    }
};
```

Comment: That solved the problem. My first C# application up until know I have been a VB.Net developer.